# Convert SQL into LINQ and Lambda

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Please is somebody able to help me convert the following SQL query into LINQ

```
select p.Description,SUM(s.TotalArea) as TotalArea from Stands s
inner join ContractProducts cp on s.Id = cp.StandId 
inner join Products p on cp.ProductId = p.Id
where s.EventId = 1
group by p.Description
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean convert to lambda ? lambda has nothing to do with sql and linq, it is only an anonymous method.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. This question looks a little lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var result= (
        from s in db.Stands
        join cp in db.ContractProducts
            on s.Id equals cp.StandId
        join p in db.Products
            on cp.ProductId equals p.Id
        where s.EventId == 1
        group p by p.Description into g
        select new
        {
            Description=g.Key,
            TotalArea = g.Sum (x =>x.TotalArea)
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Where `db` is the linqdatacontext

Comment: Thanks Arion, just had to group by s to get to the TotalArea